# Simple If statement not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

I can't see any problems with my code. But the first `if` statement never runs the alert. Anyone know why? And the function always returns zero whenever it runs even when I know 
`holidays[i] == myDate`. I think my `if`'s aren't working for som reason. Thanks in advance for any insight.

```
function checkForHoliday(date) {
    var myDate = new Date(date);

    for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {

        if (i == 5) {
            alert(holidays[i]); 
        }

        if (holidays[i] == myDate) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

*edit

changed else to:

`else if (holidays[i] != myDate && i == 9 {
            return 0;
        }`

Comment: Clearly if conditions don't work in your universe

Comment: You're returning on the first iteration on the loop regardless...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a `return` in the `else`. That's going to end the function.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is wrong, the function always return either 0 or 1 when i is 0; So i never increases to 5.